# Dynamically create CascadingValue in custom base component class

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using a custom base component class from which every custom page inhertits from.

I do not have any razor code, because it won't be templated in my my base component class - it is only supposed to contain some base logics and intialization stuff.

Now i want do wrap around a cascading value, because on any component/page which will be nested within any child level should get access to a property value of my base class. How can i do this, i tried to fake some childContent on the base component but i didnt work

```
public class BaseComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragement ChildContent {get;set;}     
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ChildContent = b =>
        {
            b.OpenComponent<CascadingValue<IBvdDataComponent>>(0);
            b.AddAttribute(1, "Name", "DataComponent");
            b.AddAttribute(2, "Value", this);
            b.CloseComponent();
         };

    }
}


   My page component:

@page "/anypage"
@inherits BaseComponent

    <div>
        <MyNestedComponent />
    </div>
```

In MyNestedComponent I want to do:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public BaseComponent BaseComponent { get; set; }
```

Whats the correct way to do this.

Comment: I don't think you are going to succeed with this approach - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22411

Comment: Not exactly what i'm looking for, because mostly they use razor syntax for getting the CascadingValue around their base component. I try to inject this dynamically.

I tried to follow the instructions of chrissainty [link](https://chrissainty.com/building-components-via-rendertreebuilder/). But I didnt succeed with it.

The buildRenderTree Method gets never calle - i don't have any idea why

Comment: Because when you descend from a component it overrides BuildRenderTree.

Comment: Alright - that make sense. I'm not aware that BuildRenderTree is completely overridden

Comment: If you look in the obj folder you can find the generated CS files for your razor files.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy to use a bit of reflection, it is possible.

```cs
public class MyBase : ComponentBase
{
    string someValue = "test";
    public MyBase()
    {
        var rf = typeof(ComponentBase).GetField("_renderFragment", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var pqr= typeof(ComponentBase).GetField("_hasPendingQueuedRender", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var nr= typeof(ComponentBase).GetField("_hasNeverRendered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        rf.SetValue(this, (RenderFragment)(builder =>
        {
            pqr.SetValue(this, false);
            nr.SetValue(this, false);
            builder.OpenComponent<CascadingValue<string>>(1);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "Value", someValue);
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)( builder2 => BuildRenderTree(builder2)));
            builder.CloseComponent();
        }));
    }
}
```

This will automatically include a CascadingValue for "someValue" to all child components.

If you don't want to use reflection, you can create your own base component that implements everything `ComponentBase` does, then modify the constructor in a similar way, but directly referencing the fields instead of using reflection.

Comment: Yes - this seems to be the way I am going to consider. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation where I needed to create a `CascadingValue` in a Base Component class because I wanted a reference to the Parent and allow custom HTML tags, only way I could figure out how to achieve this was to manually build the component tree, but instead of using `Reflection` in the Base constructor I used the `BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)` method.

```
public class Panel : ComponentBase
{
  [CascadingParameter]
  public Panel ParentPanel { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string Tag { get; set; } = "div";
      
  protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
  {
     base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

     // Add the panel element
     builder.OpenElement(0, Tag);

     // Add the CascadingValue component
     builder.OpenComponent<CascadingValue<Panel>>(1);
     builder.AddAttribute(2, "Value", this);

     // Need to add the ChildContent attribute first then add the actual ChildContent component
     // using a callback
     builder.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((builder2) => {
        builder2.AddContent(4, ChildContent);
     }));

     builder.CloseComponent();  // Close the CascadingValue
     builder.CloseElement();    // Close the Tag element
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make Mr Magoo's comment about creating your own base component  (remember, [ComponentBase is totally optional and doesn't do anything magical!](https://shauncurtis.github.io/Building-Blazor-Applications/Leaner-Meaner-Greener-Components.html)):

If you make a clone of `ComponentBase`, say, called `MyComponentBase`, the only change you would need to make to the source code is in the constructor:

```
    public MyComponentBase()
    {
        _renderFragment = builder =>
        {
            _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
            _hasNeverRendered = false;
            builder.OpenComponent<CascadingValue<string>>(1);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "Value", someValue);
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)BuildRenderTree);
            builder.CloseComponent();
        };
    }
```

The reason you might want to do this is:

1. If the `ComponentBase` implementation changes, the reflection implementation might break silently.  By rolling your own base component, the worst case scenario is that you continue to get the old behavior of `ComponentBase`.
2. (possibly) Performance, although I am only guessing that the reflection is slower here.
3. You can customize your base component further in other ways once you have broken free of `ComponentBase`.