# In Blazor, how can I dynamically change an HTML tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Let's say I have the following markup in my Blazor component:

```
<div @attributes=Attributes data-myattr="something">
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

I'd like to provide a way for the parent component to determine which tag is going to be used in place of `<div>`. Something like:

```
<@Tag @attributes=Attributes data-myattr="something">
    @ChildContent
</@Tag>
```

With @Tag being a string Parameter. Of course that doesn't work. I'm aware of templates but it doesn't work for me because I want to be in control the structure of the tag, and add extra attributes to it. I just want to give the user a choice of which tag is going to be displayed.

Comment: This seems a bit over complicated... Would you not just want to have an 'if' statement which will determine which component to render? You can also do the same with the classes/attributes which are passed in.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Newer answer

You can now use `<DynamicComponent Type=@myType Parameters=@myParameterDictionary />` where `myParameterDictionary` is a `Dictionary<string, object>`/

### Original answer

Instead of having a .razor file create a .cs file.

In the file create your class `public class MyComponent: ComponentBase`

and then override BuildRenderTree

**NOTE**: You'll need to add `?` after the `Dictionary<string, object` and `RenderFragment` in later versions to indicate they are nullable.

```cs
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
  builder.OpenElement(0, YourParameter);
  builder.CloseElement();
}
```

If you don't know exactly how to use the RenderTreeBuilder, simply create a temporary razor file and create the markup you want, then look in `obj\Debug\netstandard2.1\Razor\`

If you want to achieve this in a `.razor` file then you can create a component like this following

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace BlazorApp118.Shared
{
    public class Dynamic : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string Tag { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Tag))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Tag));

            builder.OpenElement(0, Tag);
            if (AdditionalAttributes?.Any() == true)
                builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
            if (ChildContent != null)
                builder.AddContent(2, ChildContent);
            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
<Dynamic Tag="a" AdditionalAttributes=@SomeDictionaryOfValues>
  Any content you want here
</Dynamic>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while keeping a .razor file?

Comment: @PeterMorris Thank you, one thing I did notice with adding the `ChildContent`, if you have a `CascadingValue` in the same component the `ChildContent` needs to be added via an attribute first then add the actual component from a callback [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65491337/1601882) otherwise it will throw errors

Comment: @user13256346 You'll need to be more specific, why do you think it doesn't work? I just tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: Your original answer is still helpful in case the tag name is totally unknown at compile time. `DynamicComponent` requires a class for each actual tag. Thank you very much.