# CSS isolation for a Razor component which is fully defined with a C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have a Razor component, called `RankingCell`, which is fully defined with a C# class. **There is not any `.razor` file associated to it**:

```
// RankingCell.razor.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;

namespace MyProj {
    public class RankingCell: ComponentBase {
        // Some parameters and properties

        [Parameter]
        public string CellElt { get; set; }

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) {
            /*
             * The thing which prevents me from using a "RankingCell.razor" file to define it.
             * In a .razor file it would be something like this but it is not possible:
             * 
             * <@CellElt ... >@* ... *@</@CellElt>
             * 
             * Please have a look there for for details about how I solved this issue for the component: 
             * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196493/in-blazor-how-can-i-dynamically-change-an-html-tag
             */
            builder.OpenElement(0, CellElt);

            // ...

            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to associate a stylesheet to my `RankingCell` component, so I create such a file following [Microsoft's documentation about CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation), i.e. a CSS file called `RankingCell.razor.css`:

```css
/* RankingCell.razor.css */
.ranking-cell {
    /* RankingCell style */
}
```

But when I build my project (using `dotnet build`), I have got the following error:

```
RankingCell.razor.css : error BLAZOR102: The scoped css file 'RankingCell.razor.css' was defined but no associated razor component was found for it.
```

**How to fix this BLAZOR102 issue? How to manage to associate a stylesheet with my component?**

The component does not look buggy. I have not got any compiling error when no CSS scoped file is associated to it and it works in my Blazor project.

I also tried to create an empty `RankingCell.razor` file but I had got another which told me that `BuildRenderTree` was defined elsewhere (of course since it is already fully written in `RankingCell.razor.cs`, where the component is fully defined).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: What's wrong with just adding a `.razor` file, so VS knows how to organize your isolatd files?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "partial" to RankingCell.razor.cs
like this:

```
public partial class RankingCell: ComponentBase{
}
```

Comment: It would be clearer if you say this is how you can have a .razor file and a .cs file for the same component, otherwise it could be read as a solution for the scoped CSS problem alone.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is directly possible with .NET 6/7.  The closest solution I have found is to 1) Mark the CSS file as an "Embedded Resource", 2) Have my code-only component load the CSS as a string during OnInitialized(), and 3) To then embed the loaded CSS string into the markup while rendering.

To load the CSS during OnInitialized() use something like this:

```
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var resourceName = "YourNameSpace.YourFileTitle.css";
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        CSS = reader.ReadToEnd();  // CSS is a string variable
    }
```

See [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file) for more information.

Then early within RenderBuildTree(...) do something like this:

```
            builder.OpenElement(seq++, "style");
            builder.AddMarkupContent(seq++, CSS);
            builder.CloseElement();             // body div
```